# Decrypt string with powershell that was encrypted in MSSQL with EncryptByPassPhrase()

Tags: sql-server, powershell, encryption

I have a column of some data that is encrypted simply by using the EncryptByPassPhrase("passphrase","StringtoEncrypt") function in SQL
this encrypted data is then being sent to a machine that needs to decrypt it and place it into a text file for processing.

The machine it is sent to does not have access to a SQL server at the moment.

Is it possible to decrypt this with powershell, I have looked and looked , it seems like it is basic 3DES encrypted string, but I cannot find an answer.

Comment: I would probably use an encryption key file and decrypt/re-encrypt using PowerShell's native cmdlets.

Comment: What are the cmdlets?

Comment: `ConvertFrom-SecureString` and `ConvertTo-SecureString`. The `-Key` parameter lets you specify a custom encryption key.